# Expose global environment variable from Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm working on a Jenkins plugin and I have a need to make a new environment variable available to all jobs in Jenkins. Sort of like a Jenkins global property or environment variable `env.MY_ENV_VAR`, or maybe exactly like that. I'm not sure. I just need it to be available to any script.

I already capture the value for this environment variable in one of the entries of my plugin's `config.jelly` file, which is exposed and can be set by going to `Jenkins>Manage Jenkins>Configure System>My Plugin's Settings`. So it would feel like double work for an admin to also have to set it under `Jenkins>Manage Jenkins>Configure System>Global properties`.

Then, as a second step, and thinking of maybe exposing other variables in the future, how should I go about name-spacing these? Sort of the way there are the `env`, `params`, `docker`, `scm`, `currentBuild` environment variables. What should I extend in order to have my own name-spaced environment variables? e.g.: to have a `foo` name-space and access my variables like using `foo.MY_VAR_1`, `foo.MY_VAR_2` and so on.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at how the [Docker Pipeline Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/DockerDSL.java) plugin and the [Pipeline Groovy Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/ParamsVariable.java) do this I finally ended up extending `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.GlobalVariable`, which in turn requires this dependency added to your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>workflow-cps</artifactId>
    <version>2.25</version>
</dependency>
```

I hope this helps others with a similar requirement.